# Galois group of $X^5 - X^3 - 2X^2 - 2X - 1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

So far I have found that this polynomial is irreducible, and its discriminant is a square. Therefore the Galois group it a transitive subgroup of $A_5$.

I found out that the only transitive subgroups in $A_5$ are $A_5$ and $D_{10}$. Is there a way to tell the Galois group from these two possibilities?

Answer (score 4):

$C_5$ is also a transitive subgroup of $A_5$, but yes, the discriminant is a square, so you know it must be $A_5$, $C_5$, or $D_{10}$.

Factoring over small prime numbers can give an idea of the structure of the Galois group. For example, $f(x)=x^5-x^3-2x^2-2x-1=(x+4)(x^2+3)(x^2+x+2)$ over $\mathbb{F}_5$, which instantly rules out $C_5$.

To decide between $A_5$ and $D_{10}$, recall that the Galois group of $f$ permutes its roots. Let $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_5$ be the roots of $f$, and consider the connected pentagon with the roots at each vertex:

$\hskip1.7in$[image]

Then we can look at the geometric effect of each subgroup on the roots. In particular, we look at the [resolvent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolvent_(Galois_theory)). Now calculating the resolvent does require knowing something about the roots of $f$ to some precision, but letting $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_5$ be the roots of $f$ we define the resolvent to be:
$$
p(x)=\prod_{1\le i,j\le 5}(x-(\alpha_i+\alpha_j))
$$
Then the roots of $p$ represent the ten edges of the connected pentagon, and in fact, $p$ has the same Galois group as $f$ (it's a separable polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ with the same splitting field), but exhibits much nicer qualities.

Alternatively, you can simplify the quintic into [Bring-Jerrard form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring%E2%80%93Jerrard_form#Bring.E2.80.93Jerrard_normal_form), say $g(x)=x^5+ax+b$, and then the resolvent can be written succinctly as:
$$
p(x)=x^{10}-3ax^6-11bx^5-4a^2x^2+4abx-b^2
$$
$A_5$ is the group of even permutations, and is generated by $\sigma_1=(1,2,3,4,5)$ and $\sigma_2=(1,2,3)$. If $\sigma_2$ acts on $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_5$, then only one of the edges of the pentagon can be fixed. By applying $\sigma_1$ before $\sigma_2$, we can change the edge that is fixed. Also note that all the edges of the connected pentagon can permute with one another, so $A_5$ is made up of a single orbit, and $p$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

$D_{10}$ is made up of the 5 rotations and 5 reflections of the pentagon, so the Galois group of $p$ should be made up of two orbits of length $5$: one for the rotations, and a second for the reflections. So $p$ should factor into two irreducible polynomials of degree $5$.

---

In your case, either approximating the roots of $f$ and calculating the resolvent, or reducing to Bring-Jerrard form and using the formula above, you'll see that it factors into two irreducible factors of degree $5$, and so the Galois group is $D_{10}$.

You could verify this with the following Maple code:

```
    galois(x^5-x^3-2*x^2-2*x-1);
```

This will give the following output:

```
    "5T2", {"5:2", "D(5)"}, "+", 10, {"(1 2 3 4 5)", "(1 4)(2 3)"}
```

So the Galois group is indeed $D_{10}$.